# Can you use "belongs_to' if a model can be associated to multiple owners/parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have a many-to-many relationship between Policy(s) and Rule(s). A policy can have multiple rules. A given rule can belong to multiple policies. There's a mapping table PolicyRule(s) that exists (plus other metadata about the relation). From what I understand doing `has_and_belongs_to_many` would not work if the mapping table has other columns. So I'm looking into doing a `has_many :through`. This [doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) has an example of Document -> Section -> Paragraphs that I'm following but I'm not sure if it's correct for me to say that rule `belongs_to: policy_rule` when it can belong to more than one.

```rb
class Policy < Base
    has_many :rule, through: :policy_rule
end

class PolicyRule < Base
    belongs_to :policy
    has_many :rules
end

class Rule < Base
    belongs_to: :policy_rule
end
```

Comment: Your casing is incorrect. You should be using `belong_to :policy`, not `:Policy`. This matters a lot in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define these associations

```rb
class Policy < Base
  has_many :policy_rules
  has_many :rules, through: :policy_rules
end

class PolicyRule < Base
  belongs_to :policy
  belongs_to :rule
end

class Rule < Base
  has_many :policy_rules
  has_many :policies, through: :policy_rules
end
```

And then you can get all rules for one policy and all policies for one rule.

```rb
policy = Policy.find(1)
policy.rules

rule = Rule.find(1)
rule.policies
```

Also you can create new records like this:

```rb
policy = Policy.find(1)
policy.rules.create(rule_params)

rule = Rule.find(1)
rule.policies.create(policy_params)
```

And many other operations. Refer to these docs [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)